# jasperreport - loop a arraylist returned from scriptlets

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am try to loop a ArrayList which is return by a scriptlet in jasperreport. when I try dispaly this Arraylist, its displayed in one field, what I want to let it display row by row in detail band, anyone can provide any help, thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to include relevant code.  We could help you tons easier.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to advice you to use JRBeanCollectionDataSource. Check following method:

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameterMap, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
```

In JRBeanCollectionDataSource pass your arraylist, it should then display list items row by row.

**EDIT**

Use custom bean class, let say if yoy want to display user details in Report then do something like:

```
class User{
private String userName;
private String address;
....
/*
Getters and setters
*/ 
}
```

Create `List<User>` and pass it to JRBeanCollectionDataSource.
In jrxml file use fields like:

```
<field name="userName" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[userName]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

name must be same as your variable name in bean class - User.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks you so much about your advice, my report is on the jasper server, and in the scriptlets, I have two way to set or return this list,one is set into a field or variable, another way is return directly. I was try to use this way like you said, but I should do in report? how can I return this jasperPrint object back to report? and display it

Comment: this is part of that method in scriptlet:
<blink>JRDataSource dataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(arrList);  
  try {
   JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport("/Definitions/Cross_business_monthly.jrxml", null, dataSource);
   this.setFieldValue("test", jasperPrint);
  } catch (JRException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }</blink>